# Bootstrap 4 last version Carousal buttons is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my next/prev buttons are not working. Can someone help me. Thanks!I am new to coding I have researched a bunch and tried different things but nothing is working.

```
<section class="section-main">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: best example here - https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: Have you made sure to include all the relevant JavaScript libraries?

Comment: Your code is functioning properly when plopped into Bootply.  The only concession I had to make was specifying a `height` to your images, and only because they weren't able to load.

Comment: thank you it is working now the problem was with the javascript libraries was not included so I copied and pasted the <script> lines in the answer of mr tony and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the required javascript libraries that Bootstrap uses in between the head tags at the top of your html file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

An example of what the full html file would look like with the above libraries inbetween the head tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="section-main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide1.png" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide2.png" alt="Second slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/slide3.png" alt="Third slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

A link to the documentation Bootstrap provides explaining how to get started.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

I hope this helps

Comment: I copied and pasted the the 3 line with <script> and it worked thank you man so much

Answer (score 1):

I created [an example on codepen](https://codepen.io/lucozhao/pen/QORMKy) based on [bootstrap document](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

The example demonstrates html, css, js codes to make the carousel work.

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

Please double check if you add required libraries including

```
jquery, 
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.css.
```

I added them through **Pen Settings**.

Comment: thank you for your answer it included it and it is working now Jim

Comment: @Ahmed You are very welcome. If possible, please help vote up my answer as I am new to this awesome QA site.